# Cloud Firestore: CollectionReference

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a singleton service which creates a `CollectionReference` once and then operates on the documents as needed.

Is Cloud Firestore Java SDK `CollectionReference` thread-safe? Couldn't find the info in the docs.

Thanks in advance.